# How to calculate the limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The question is calculate limit of sequence

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{\left(2\,\sqrt[\Large n]{\, n\,}\, -
\,\sqrt[\Large n]{\, 2\,}\right)^{n}}{n^2}
$$
I'm trying to simplify the equation, like divide $\,\sqrt[\Large n]{\, n\,}\,$, but can't get more.  I drew the continuous function plot, which shows value tends to $0.4$.

Do any method show more details about this question ？.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-\sqrt[n]{2}\right)^n&=\left(2e^{\frac1n \log(n)}-e^{\frac1n\log(2)}\right)^n\\\\
&=\left(1+\frac1n\log(n^2/2)+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)^n\\\\
&=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac1n\log(n^2/2)+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{n\left(\frac1n\log(n^2/2)+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{n^2}{2}+O\left(n\log^2(n)\right)\tag1
\end{align}.$$

Upon dividing $(1)$ by $n^2$ and letting $n\to \infty,$ we find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-\sqrt[n]{2}\right)^n}{n^2}=\frac12$$

Comment: @Mark Viola please check the second line.

Comment: Also, the 4th line

Comment: In 4th line you, use log expression. You don't think that there should be many more terms continuing with ascending power of $\frac{\log(\frac{n^2}{2})}{n} $.

Comment: But insted, you only use $\circ(\frac{\log(n^2)}{n^2}) $

Comment: @Subhajit Thank you for catching the typographical error.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: My doubt about 4th line , is not clear still. You didn't change it.

Comment: @Subhajit There is nothing to change.  Are you familiar with the "Big O" notation?  If so, then you understand that $\left(\frac{\log(n^2/2)}{n}\right)^2=O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)$, right?

Comment: Hmm, now it's ok! Thanks!!

Comment: There is a mistake in your proof. $$e^{n\left(\frac1n\log(n^2/2)+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)}=\frac{n^2}{2}\cdot e^{O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n}\right)}=\frac{n^2}{2}\cdot\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{n^2}{2}+O\left(n\log^2(n)\right).$$

Comment: @angelo Indeed.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: No, I did not downvote you. I have just told you about that mistake.

Comment: @angelo Thank you Angelo.  And much appreciate the catch.

Comment: @MarkViola many thx for your answer and i should to strength comprehension of taylor formula

Answer (score 1):

Another way to calculate your limit.

Since $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2}=1,\;$ we get that $$a_n=\frac{2\sqrt[n]{n}-\sqrt[n]{2}-\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^2}{\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^2}\xrightarrow{\text{as}\;n\to\infty}0$$ and $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(1+a_n\right)^\frac{1}{a_n}=e.$$

Moreover, it results that
$$\frac{(2\sqrt[n]{n}-\sqrt[n]{2})^n}{n^2}=\left[\left(1+a_n\right)^\frac{1}{a_n}\right]^{na_n}.$$

Now we are going to calculate $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(na_n)\;$.

$$na_n=-\left[\frac{n\left(\sqrt[n]{2}-1\right)+n\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^2}{\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^2}\right].$$

But $$\;\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n\left(\sqrt[n]{2}-1\right)=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=\ln2\;\;$$ and $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} n\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^2=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left[\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln n}{n}}\right)^2\cdot\frac{\ln^2n}{n}\right]=1^2\cdot0=0$$ therefore $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(na_n)=-\ln2$$ so $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{(2\sqrt[n]{n}-\sqrt[n]{2})^n}{n^2}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+a_n\right)^\frac{1}{a_n}\right]^{na_n}=e^{-\ln2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: many thx! It's really a flexible transform